# Do I need to install IntelliJ IDEA if I already have Android Studio installed?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

The title pretty much sums it up.  I'm brand new to IntelliJ IDEA, and it's not clear to me if I need separate installs, one for my Android projects and one for my vanilla Java (and beyond) projects.  I've read through the docs and couldn't find an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be working with many non-Android Java projects, then IntelliJ is definitely the way to go. You may even find that after you start using it you will stop using Android Studio altogether.

IntelliJ includes most of what Android Studio provides for Android development as well as fantastic support for other types of projects. Additionally, IntelliJ has far fewer issues for Android development.

As for running both - they keep all their files separate (config, etc) and it is perfectly safe to run both (even at the same time).

If you do decide to use both then I would just advise you to keep your Android SDK install in a separate location - it just makes it easier to manage and you can point both at a single updated target :)

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio is self-contained for Android projects. If you're going to be doing significant plain Java development, you may prefer to use IntelliJ, becuase Android Studio is in many ways tuned to doing Android development, and could be restrictive for other types of projects.

For example, Android Studio is designed to work with the Gradle build system, which may not be what you want for Java projects; it's possible to use Android Studio with IntelliJ's built-in Java builder, though you can't create new projects that way.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't quite answer my question.  I understand that AS is designed specifically for Android projects (which is why I installed it).  What I'm wondering is, since I plan to do plenty of non-Android Java development, should I (and can I) install IntelliJ IDEA *in addition to* AS?  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I've edited my answer a couple times since I first posted it; is it still unclear?